# How to feed a 12V DC timer circuit from 220V AC power lines?

Tags: relay

[image: The Schematics of the circuit I intend to design also, the resistor I forgot to mention its value (the one just before the capacitor) is 51 kΩ, I don't know how to draw schematics by apps (I tried a couple of times, but they were so time consuming and hard) so I did it by hand, sorry if it's not so clear]
The schematics of the circuit I intend to design also, the resistor I forgot to mention its value (the one just before the capacitor) is 51 kΩ, I don't know how to draw schematics by apps (I tried a couple of times, but they were so time consuming and hard) so I did it by hand, sorry if it's not so clear.

I'm a physics student (undergrad senior) and I do electronics as a hobby for 5 years, but I am not so keen on using ICs and MOSFETs yet. I wanted to design a timer circuit to turn a device (powered by 220 V AC) on for 2 minutes by a trigger button and I did, but my problem is how to feed the circuit from 220 V AC line. The circuit is basically a 2N2222 BJT in series with a 12V DC relay, and the BJT is controlled by a voltage divider which has a capacitor that charges after 2 minutes (I found the resistors and capacitor's value empirically, by trial and error) and the button is connected parallel to the capacitor to discharge it through a 1.5 Ω shunt resistor. I know I can power the circuit by a 12 V adapter, but the circuit is inside of a device that had a limited place for its main board (and also I don't want to use an adapter anyways, the device is an standalone device with one AC power plug, I don't want to use an extra adapter to power a 240 mW timer circuit, I want to design a low power feed circuit for it myself). And also, I know I can make a low power linear power supply (transformer, bridge rectifier, capacitor and inductor), but I wonder if there is a better option, I can rectify 220 V AC to 340 V DC and use a shunt resistor to bump the voltage down when the circuit is drawing current but that would consume at least 3 W of power (the timer circuit itself draws nothing more than 240 mW) using divider resistors after rectifying AC consumes 26 W or so, which is so high, I mean what do they do in these time based surge protectors (the power strips that have timer circuit that protects appliances from voltage fluctuations, how do they power the 12 V DC relay, I mean, I haven't seen any transformers or signs of a linear voltage transformation inside of them, when opening them up and seeing their boards)? I usually don't see the components of a linear or switched mode 12 V DC adapter on circuits that operate on 220 V AC, dedicated to the relay used on them. Can anyone please help? I can provide more details if needed.
I looked all over the internet and searched in many different ways, but couldn't find an appropriate answer, I haven't asked any questions online, this is the first time I'm asking a question on a community site (so I apologize if I explained too much or said unnecessary or unrelated details, I don't know the exact costumes of asking questions this way), I would be very thankful if anyone could provide an appropriate answer.

**Edit:**
I made the circuit with a low current (300 mA the one I found on the market) LED driver circuit, and then connected its output to a filter capacitor and then connected an adjustable low power step down converter as its load and set the output voltage of the step down converter to 12.6 V that my timer circuit was set up for and now the device is working as intended. I am really thankful from everyone who took the time to provide helpful answers to me that will be so useful in my future designs, real thanks for all the helpful comments, answers and replies.
[image: This is the LED driver I used to power the circuit, I should have fixed it quickly, the person needed the device, and I was busy hooking up the circuit these 2 days, and I couldn't see some of the answers. If I had more time to see the recent answers, I might have designed a better, cheaper, more efficient and smaller circuit, I will use your helpful advices on my next projects. Thanks,]

This is the LED driver I used to power the circuit, I should have fixed the device quickly, the person needed the device, and I was busy hooking up the circuit these 2 days, and I couldn't see some of the answers. If I had more time to see the recent answers, I might have designed a better, cheaper, more efficient and smaller circuit, I will use your helpful advices on my next projects. Thanks,

Comment: While what you want to do is possible, it is dangerous fora professional and possibly lethal for a hobbyist.  Please post your schematic so we can see more about the circuit you have.

Comment: @AnalogKid I added the hand drawn schematics at the beginning of the question description, please let me know if any other details are needed, thanks

Comment: Don't draw AC mains neutral like it's "GND".  Be careful tying electronics to that, because if you flip the plug over, it's now energized at 220V.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yes, you are right, that would cause some problems in other more complicated circuits, I should have drawn the schematics by Live and Neutral (form L to N), I'll try to be more careful with that, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are switch-mode circuits that drop from line voltage to 12V but unless you really know what you’re doing it’s much better to use a transformer, this provides isolation from the mains supply which makes everything much safer on the low-voltage side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is that the same kind of 12 V switched mode circuits that are used to power the relay inside a timer based surge protector power strip? If so, what can that basic circuit be? And if not, what type of circuit is that? (Now that you mentioned, I remembered seeing a PWM IC in surge protectors' circuits)

Comment: I’m not sure about surge protectors, I would think that they need to isolate very quickly and so would use solid-state rather than a relay.  I’ve seen single-stage converters in cookers, washing machines etc that produce a non-isolated DC output.  The chips are often 7-pin DIL package devices, one of the normal 8 pins being left off to provide more clearance for the pin that carries the phase input.

Comment: Thank you so much Frog, I'll check out single stage converters, I've searched it and the same IC I had seen besides the relay on the old surge protector PCB came up. I'll dig into that to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

It's safer to use an off-the-shelf 220 V AC Timer, with 'On Time' function.

[image]

Comment: Thanks vu2nan, but the device had a electronical timer circuit before I replace its main board (with NE555 IC, better than the one I designed with a BJT), and while using the timer you mentioned is far better than designing one, these kind of ac timers are not readily available and they are hard to find in my region and even if I could find one, it would not fit inside of the place for the main board of the device and I may need to change the configurations of the control buttons as the timer would not be controlled by the switches on the device

Comment: Anytime! I'm sorry my answer does not help.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient and simple way to get a low current power supply is reducing the grid voltage with a capacitor, a zener to limit, a rectifier and a filter. See schematics for guiding, and calculate for your needs.
R1 is for current limit, in case power is connected at peak voltage; R2 will discharge C1 when it is not powered; zener should be selected for desired voltage output + voltage drop of rectifier (0.7 V).

Remember that the circuit directly to the grid. BTW, the 1.5 Ohm resistor makes no sense, as the 10 kOhm will limit the transistor base current.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, I really appreciate your detailed answer on the design of a low power feed circuit, I was stuck on this for quite a while and I'll test this circuit with caution to see the results. And also which app did you use for drawing the schematics? And yes I was wrong about 1.5 kΩ in my schematics, I'll edit it, because it was 51 kΩ I misread the colour code (it was green brown orange gold, but I misread it as brown green orange gold). I'll mark your answer as best answer and will close the thread.

Comment: @TheLonelyBoy: I used LTSpice , It is a simulation free software.

Comment: Thanks Bravale, I'll check it out and try to use it, a schematic drawing app comes very useful for my electronic class on next semester.